# I can't able to open bottomsheet behavior which contains webview from a java class using activity context in android, here is my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx, bottom-sheet

BottomSheet Behavior is not working when I inflate the layout programmatically, I also used activity context to inflate the layout, if I use this method direct into activity than it is working fine, but from another class it is not working

```
    final View dialogView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    
    final WebView webView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    
    final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(webView);
   
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


slider_web_view.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I added webview in coordinate layout and also applie this to webview = "app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"

Comment: share your slider_web_view.xml file also

Comment: @AbdurRehman here I am attaching slider_web_view.xml file